# How long does KTable data maintain in Kafka? Or how can I control the time

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

I know Kafka uses RocksDb internally. 
If I use KTable to store data dictionary, will it be deleted after a specific time? If that so, how can I make it last unlimited time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KTables and the underlying RocksDB state stores have semantics like a compacted topic in Kafka. The retention is not based on time, but rather a record becomes eligible for deletion if you send a message with a given key and an null value to the input topic.